# Как очистить консоль в Java во время действия программы

Tags: java, консоль

Облазил весь интернет но не нашел ответа. Хочу написать простенький консольный **to-do list**. Хочу чтобы когда я переходил по пунктам меню, консоль очищалась. Как это можно реализовать в рамках консольного Java-приложения? Причем я имею ввиду не очищать консоль при помощи команд самой командной строки операционной системы, а чтобы это работало в той же **Intellij IDEA**.

Comment: Вы можете просто вывести много переводов строк, чтобы предыдущая информация ушла далеко наверх. И это будет работать везде.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4888362/5308259

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы очистить экран, можно использовать [управляющие последовательности ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI). Такие последовательности начинаются со специального escape-символа `\033` (или `\u001b`), после которого следует символ `[`, далее следует команда.

В нашем случае, для очистки всего экрана, нужно выполнить две команды:

1. `H` — переместить курсор на определенную позицию. По умолчанию передвигает курсор в начало экрана. Команда `10;5H` передвигает курсор на 10 строку в 5 колонку.
2. `J` — очистить экран от курсора до конца экрана. Также есть вариации `1J` и `2J`.

Таким образом, чтобы очистить терминал, нужно распечатать две последовательности:

```java
System.out.print("\033[H\033[J");
```

Этот способ будет работать в терминалах, которые поддерживают управляющие символы ANSI.