# Как улучшить Java код из Основной части?

Tags: java, алгоритм, чистый-код

Это маленькое консольное приложение:

```
static void taskDisplay(int taskNumber, HashMap<Integer, String> problemsAndAnswers){
    System.out.println(problemsAndAnswers.get(taskNumber));
}

static void creatingTasks(HashMap<Integer, String> problemsAndAnswers){
    problemsAndAnswers.put(1, "Напишите программу, которая выводит на экран строку  \"Hello world!\"");
    problemsAndAnswers.put(2, "Закомментируйте ненужные строки так, чтобы в выводе получилось:\n" +
            "\"// - Это комментарий) Это не сложно\"");
    problemsAndAnswers.put(3, "Напишите программу, которая выведет на экран \"Hello Programming!\" (без кавычек) на 2 строках, по слову на каждой (см. пример вывода)");
    problemsAndAnswers.put(4, """
                    Закомментируйте ненужные строки так, что бы в выводе получилось:
                    Я прекрасно понимаю разницу между System.out.println()
                    и System.out.print(). А ты?""");
}

static void clearConsole(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<Integer, String> problemsAndAnswers = new HashMap<>();
    creatingTasks(problemsAndAnswers);
    System.out.println("В этом блоке 4 задачи!");

    while (true){
        int taskNumber = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        if (taskNumber >= 1 && taskNumber <= 4) {
            switch (taskNumber) {
                case 1:
                    taskDisplay(1, problemsAndAnswers);
                    scan.nextLine();
                    getSolution1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    taskDisplay(2, problemsAndAnswers);
                    scan.nextLine();
                    getSolution2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    taskDisplay(3, problemsAndAnswers);
                    scan.nextLine();
                    getSolution3();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    taskDisplay(4, problemsAndAnswers);
                    scan.nextLine();
                    getSolution4();
                    break;
            }
            scan.nextLine();
            clearConsole();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

}
static void getSolution1(){
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}

static void getSolution2(){
    //System.out.println("#  - Это комментарий) Стоп, это не тот язык");
    System.out.println("// - Это комментарий) Это не сложно");
    /*System.out.println("// - Это не комментарий) Это не сложно");
    System.out.println("// - Это комментарий) Это сложно");
    System.out.println("// - Это не комментарий) Это не сложно");
    System.out.println("можно даже попробовать многострочный комментарий");*/
}

static void getSolution3(){
     System.out.println("Hello\nProgramming!");
}
static void getSolution4(){
    //System.out.println("Я прекрасно понимаю разницу ");
    System.out.print("Я прекрасно понимаю разницу ");
    System.out.println("между System.out.println()");
    //System.out.print("между System.out.println()");
    //System.out.println("и System.out.print(). ");
    System.out.print("и System.out.print(). ");
    System.out.println("А ты?");
    //System.out.print("А ты?");
}
```

Ее суть в том, что есть несколько задач, у которых есть номер. Нужно принимать номер задачи, затем  выводить ее условие. Далее программа должна дождаться ввода Enter и вывести ответ. После чего опять дождать ввода Enter, очистить консоль и ожидать ввода номера задачи. У меня вопрос: как улучшить этот код?
P.s. как очистить консоль - я не нашел информации, по этому создал метод который просто выводит много пустых строк. Если вы знаете как очистить консоль - буду благодарен, если поделитесь информацией)

Comment: Непонятно что здесь надо улучшить. Напиши более конкретно.

Answer (score 2):

Косметические улучшения:

- убрать мусорные комментарии с неиспользуемым кодом
- убрать дублированный код в операторе `switch` -- в `case` останется только вызов конкретного решения
- отрефакторить метод `creatingTasks` -- либо переименовать его в `fillTaskMap` (более соответствующее название), либо сделать так, чтобы этот метод соответствовал названию, то есть, возвращал полностью готовую мапу:

```java
static Map<Integer, String> createTasks() {
    return Map.of(
        1, "Напишите программу, которая выводит на экран строку  \"Hello world!\"",
        2, "Закомментируйте ненужные строки так, чтобы в выводе получилось:\n" +
            "\"// - Это комментарий) Это не сложно\"",
        3, "Напишите программу, которая выведет на экран \"Hello Programming!\" (без кавычек) на 2 строках, по слову на каждой (см. пример вывода)",
        4, """
           Закомментируйте ненужные строки так, что бы в выводе получилось:
           Я прекрасно понимаю разницу между System.out.println()
           и System.out.print(). А ты?"""
    );
}
```

- Переименовать метод `taskDisplay` -- более корректное название было бы `displayTask`, хотя для данной реализации (вызова `System.out.println`) он не особо нужен.

---

Радикальный рефакторинг:

- создать отдельный класс `MyTask` (или использовать кортеж `record` если используется Java 16 и выше), чтобы инкапсулировать строку сообщения и ссылку на соответствующий метод (в данном случае можно использовать интерфейс `Runnable`)
- переделать мапу, чтобы она хранила объекты `MyTask`
- использовать статическую неизменяемую мапу, заполненную нужными данными без метода `createTaskMap`
- упростить логику и убрать оператор `if` с проверкой диапазона значений и `switch-case`.
- перед чтением целого числа из сканера следует добавить проверку `scan.hasNextInt`, чтобы не возникали ненужные исключения при некорректном вводе

*Дополнение*
Метод `main` можно сократить до нескольких строк, упростив условие в цикле `while`, если добавить такие улучшения:

- сделать экземпляр сканера статическим членом класса
- реализовать отдельные методы для получения задачи `readTask` и её обработки `handleTask`

Пример *переписанного кода*

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    
    record MyTask(String message, Runnable task) {}
    
    static Map<Integer, MyTask> taskMap = Map.of(
        1, new MyTask("Напишите программу, которая выводит на экран строку  \"Hello world!\"", MyClass::getSolution1),
        2, new MyTask("Закомментируйте ненужные строки так, чтобы в выводе получилось:\n" +
            "\"// - Это комментарий) Это не сложно\"", MyClass::getSolution2),
        3, new MyTask("Напишите программу, которая выведет на экран \"Hello Programming!\" (без кавычек) на 2 строках, по слову на каждой (см. пример вывода)", MyClass::getSolution3),
        4, new MyTask("""
           Закомментируйте ненужные строки так, что бы в выводе получилось:
           Я прекрасно понимаю разницу между System.out.println()
           и System.out.print(). А ты?""", MyClass::getSolution4)
    );

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("В этом блоке 4 задачи! Введите цифру от 1 до 4.");
    
        MyTask task;
        while (null != (task = readTask())) {
            handleTask(task);
        }
        System.out.println("Пока!");
    }

    static MyTask readTask() {
        return scan.hasNextInt() ? taskMap.get(scan.nextInt()) : null;
    }
    
    static void handleTask(MyTask task) {
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(task.message());
        scan.nextLine();
        task.task().run();
        scan.nextLine();
        clearConsole();
    }
    
    static void clearConsole() {
        //System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
        //System.out.flush();
        System.out.println("-----\nСледующая попытка!\n-----\n");
    }
    
    static void getSolution1() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
    
    static void getSolution2() {
        System.out.println("// - Это комментарий) Это не сложно");
    }
    
    static void getSolution3() {
         System.out.println("Hello\nProgramming!");
    }
    
    static void getSolution4(){
        System.out.print("Я прекрасно понимаю разницу ");
        System.out.println("между System.out.println()");
        System.out.print("и System.out.print(). ");
        System.out.println("А ты?");
    }
}
```

*Замечание:* Метод `clearConsole` выводит сообщение о следующей попытке, но если приложение будет запускаться в ANSI-совместимой консоли, то можно раскомментировать строки, тогда при выводе последовательности `"\033[H\033[2J"` консоль очистится.
См. [Как очистить консоль в Java во время действия программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315049/)